# Process of deploying changes to Spark-Streaming to production

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What is the process followed to make some changes on production in Spark-Streaming without any downtime?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Upgrading Application Code , Please refer to spark-streaming documentation .

> Upgrading Application Code If a running Spark Streaming application
>   needs to be upgraded with new application code, then there are two
>   possible mechanisms.
>
> The upgraded Spark Streaming application is started and run in
>   parallel to the existing application. Once the new one (receiving the
>   same data as the old one) has been warmed up and is ready for prime
>   time, the old one be can be brought down. Note that this can be done
>   for data sources that support sending the data to two destinations
>   (i.e., the earlier and upgraded applications).
>
> The existing application is shutdown gracefully (see
>   StreamingContext.stop(...) or JavaStreamingContext.stop(...) for
>   graceful shutdown options) which ensure data that has been received is
>   completely processed before shutdown. Then the upgraded application
>   can be started, which will start processing from the same point where
>   the earlier application left off. Note that this can be done only with
>   input sources that support source-side buffering (like Kafka, and
>   Flume) as data needs to be buffered while the previous application was
>   down and the upgraded application is not yet up. And restarting from
>   earlier checkpoint information of pre-upgrade code cannot be done. The
>   checkpoint information essentially contains serialized
>   Scala/Java/Python objects and trying to deserialize objects with new,
>   modified classes may lead to errors. In this case, either start the
>   upgraded app with a different checkpoint directory, or delete the
>   previous checkpoint directory.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: How would you do this for structured streaming with checkpointing? Looks like the second job will error as the first job will have already written to the checkpoint

Comment: @techalicious You would have to change the checkpoint Path for the new version